# Class not found exception : javax/faces/component/UIComponent

Tags: jsf, myfaces

I trying to upgrade myfaces from 2.0.18 to the latest 3.0.1 but I am getting Class not found exception with the below error

noClassDefFound: javax/faces/component/UIComponent

Could you please let me know what is causing this issue or where can i get this class to add.

Comment: Please don't use irrelevant tags. Java, PrimeFaces or JSTL have nothing to do with your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that version of MyFaces is for `jakarta` libs not `javax` libs.

From Apache MyFaces docs version 3.0.1:

> "The upcoming Jakarta Faces 3.0. It's equals to JSF 2.3 but with
> "jakarta.faces" packages and constants instead of "javax.faces"."

https://github.com/apache/myfaces